# Calculate the Probability for Binary Matrix

Tags: probability, combinatorics, computer-science

Consider a binary matrix of dimension $m\times n$. Suppose the probability of occurrence of 1 is $p$ in any row of the matrix. Each row of the matrix is independent to each other. The all possible distinct number of binary columns is $2^n$. What is probability of occurrence **all possible $n-tuple$ column vectors** in the matrix of dimension $m\times n$?

Comment: I assume that the second sentence means that each *element* of the matrix is $1$ with probability $p$, but is the third sentence talking about independence of random variables or about linear independence (i.e. the matrix is non-singular)?

Comment: I mean the rows are distinct. I do not mean that the matrix in non-singular.